# How to make a function with inferred nillable comparable generics?

Tags: go, generics

Consider the following function:

```golang
func NilCompare[T comparable](a *T, b *T) bool {
    if a == nil && b == nil {
        // if both nil, we consider them equal
        return true
    }
    if a == nil || b == nil {
        // if either is nil, then they are clearly not equal
        return false
    }
    return *a == *b
}
```

This function works.  However, when I call it, I must supply the type, as Go cannot infer (`cannot infer T`) it, e.g. `NilCompare[string](a, b)`, where `a` and `b` are `*string`.

If I modify `T` to be `*comparable` and `a` and `b` to be `T`, I get this error instead:
`cannot use type comparable outside a type constraint: interface is (or embeds) comparable`

I am using Go 1.19.2.

```bash
$ go version
go version go1.19.2 linux/amd64
```

Ironically, my IDE (GoLand 2022.2.3) believes that the above function should be inferrable.

Is there a way to make a function that take nillable `comparable` and make it inferrable?  Or am I doing it correct, but I need to help the `go` function along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference just works, in this case. You simply can't infer `T` using literal `nil`, as `NilCompare(nil, nil)` because that doesn't really carry type information.

To test your function with `nil`s do this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a *string = nil
    var b *string = nil
    // a and b are explicitly typed
    res := NilCompare(a, b) // T inferred
    fmt.Println(res) // true
}
```

this also would work:

```
func main() {
    // literal nil converted to *string
    res := NilCompare((*string)(nil), (*string)(nil)) // T inferred
    fmt.Println(res) // true
}
```